# Sails: How to return a value from the find function

Tags: javascript, node.js, return, sails.js, waterline

I am working in sails js. And i want to return the variable `sequence[0].NextValue`;. But I am  not getting it.

```
function AutoGenerate(tablename) 
    {
        Sequence.find({TableName:tablename}).exec(function(err,sequence){
            if(err)
            {
                console.log("err");
                return res.negotiate(err);

            }
            else
            {
                console.log(sequence);
                var intCurrentNo = sequence[0].NextValue;
                var intNextNo = sequence[0].NextValue + sequence[0].IncrementBy;                    
                if (intNextNo < sequence[0].MinimumValue || intNextNo > sequence[0].MaximumValue)
                {
                    console.log("Error While Updating UserId")
                    return res.badRequest('Next value not between the Minimum and Maximum value');

                }
                else
                {
                    sequence[0].NextValue = intNextNo;
                    console.log(intNextNo);
                    sequence[0].save(function(err)
                        {
                            if (err) 
                            {
                                console.log("error while update");
                                return res.negotiate(err);
                            }
                            else    
                            {
                                console.log("Incremented");
                                console.log(sequence[0].NextValue); 
                                return sequence[0].NextValue; 
                            }
                        });


                    }
                }
        });
    }
```

But the `Sequence.find({TableName:tablename})`  function does not returning any value. Please help me to get rid of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return a value cause it's an asynchronous method you have to do it with callbacks :

```
function AutoGenerate(tablename, callback)
{
  Sequence.find({TableName : tablename}).exec(function (err, sequence)
  {

    if (err)
    {
      console.log("err");
      callback(err);

    }
    else
    {
      console.log(sequence);

      var intCurrentNo = sequence[0].NextValue;
      var intNextNo    = sequence[0].NextValue + sequence[0].IncrementBy;

      if (intNextNo < sequence[0].MinimumValue || intNextNo > sequence[0].MaximumValue)
      {
        console.log("Error While Updating UserId")
        callback(new Error('Next value not between the Minimum and Maximum value'));

      }
      else
      {

        sequence[0].NextValue = intNextNo;
        console.log(intNextNo);
        sequence[0].save(function (err)
        {
          if (err)
          {
            console.log("error while update");
            callback(err);
          }
          else
          {
            console.log("Incremented");
            console.log(sequence[0].NextValue);
            callback(null, sequence[0].NextValue);

          }
        });


      }
    }


  });
}
```

And call it like this :

```
AutoGenerate("myTableName", function(err, nextValue){
    if(err){res.negotiate(err);}
    else {/* DO WHAT YOU WANT */}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, and i need to store the callback value in a variable. So could i call the function like this `var  value = AutoGenerate("myTableName");`

Comment: No you can't do this cause it's asynchronous , but you don't need to cause all you code who use "nextValue" have to be in the callback. So you variable is directly  "nextValue". Why asynchronous method it's impossible to do var value = toto(); you have to use callbacks.